# has_may for a vote app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm new on rails and I'm trying to make my own simple vote application. I have two models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :photo
  has_many :votes

  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300" }

  before_save { |product| product.title = title.titlecase }

  validates :title, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  validates :photo, :attachment_presence => true

end


class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  attr_accessible :user_id
end
```

here is the product controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController

    http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "dhh", :password => "secret", :except => [:index]

    def index
        @products = Product.all
    end

    def indexprv
        @products = Product.all
    end

    def show
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def edit
        @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @product = Product.new
    end

    def create
        @product = Product.new(params[:product])
        if @product.save
            redirect_to @product
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def update
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if @product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        flash[:success] = "Producto Actualizado"
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    Product.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Producto Eliminado."
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

I have many questions.

How can I show the total votes per products on my index page of products?

How can I create a button on my index product page to add a vote for a product?

I don't know how to do this and I couldn't find any tutorial o blog with a similar example.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your index view probably already loops through every product you have (either by a partial or by a loop). In your loop/partial do something like: (assuming the variable product has a instance of a product)

```
product.votes.count
```

to get the number of votes. To get a button to add a vote do something along the lines of:

```
link_to "Add Vote", new_product_vote_path(product), action: :new
```

A good tutorial that covers many aspects of rails is: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#top

Edit:

Your index method in your controller gives you an array of every product you have. So if you do something like this in your index view (if your using erb):

```
<ul>
<% @products.each do |product| %>
 <li> 
  <%= product.title %>: <br />
  Votes: <%= product.votes.count %> <br />
  <%= link_to "Add Vote", new_product_vote_path(product), action: :new %>
 </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

it should do what you want

Comment: Thanks Ian Armit but when I try this product.votes.count I get NoMethodError: undefined method `votes' for nil:NilClass and I don't understand why

Comment: the variable product needs to be assigned an instance of a Product, if you post your controller and index view code it would help.

Comment: Ready, I just published the product controller

Comment: thanks, it works. But I have another question, how can I vote for the product from the index page??? I mean, how can I modify the create action on my product control???

Comment: You would have to link to the create action in the `link_to` statement instead of the new action, but you will need to pass the proper parameters as well which I can't help you with.